# Redux State not updating. Redux tools show empty

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Good evening everyone.  React super noob here.  trying to update the state on my reducer, but it will not update for the life of me.  Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

**code below:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchCodes,fetchLang } from "../actions";

class CodeDisplay extends React.Component{
 
    componentDidMount(){      
        this.props.fetchCodes();        
    }
    componentDidUpdate(){
        this.props.fetchLang();
    }

   renderCreate(){
       return(
        <Link to={'/add'} className="ui primary basic button">Add Code</Link>
       )       
   }

   renderTableData() {
      return this.props.code.map((c,i) => {
         const { id, CodeName, Code, DateAdded } = c //destructuring
         return (
            <tr key={i}>
               <td><i className="keyboard icon"></i></td> 
               <td>{id}</td>
               <td>
                    <Link to={`/show/${c.id}`} className="header">
                        {CodeName}
                    </Link>
               </td>
               <td>{Code}</td>
               <td>{DateAdded}</td>
               <td>
                    <div className ="ui buttons">
                        <Link to={`/update/${c.id}`} className="ui button primary">Edit</Link>
                    <div className ="or"></div>
                        <Link to={`/delete/${c.id}`} className="ui button negative">Delete</Link>
                    </div>
                </td>              
            </tr>
         )
      })
   }

    render (){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.renderCreate()}
                <table className="ui single line table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Code Name</th>
                            <th>Code</th>
                            <th>Date Added</th>
                        </tr>
                        {this.renderTableData()}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return {
        code: Object.values(state.code),
        lang:state.lang
    }
}
```

**my reducer below**

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import { 
    FETCH_LANG
} from "../actions/types";

export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LANG:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**combined reducer below:**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as form} from "redux-form";
import CodeReducer from "./CodeReducer";
import LangReducer from "./LangReducer";

export default combineReducers({
    code:CodeReducer,
    lang: LangReducer,
    form:form    
});
```

**index.js below:**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './components/App.js'
import reducers from './reducers';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

**Action creator below:**

```
export const fetchLang = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await api.get('/GetLang');

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_LANG, payload: response.data });
};
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: I see where you import `fetchLang` but where are you connecting your actions to the calls to `dispatch` in the `CodeDisplay`? It seems you are missing the `mapDispatchToProps` function.

Comment: Thanks for your response Drew.  There is a mapStateToProps function at the bottom of the first piece of code above.  Maybe that is where the issue recides.

Comment: Well, `mapStateToProps` is the first argument to the `connect` HOC, the second is `mapDispatchToProps` to create/inject the action creators as props. This second part is what I'm asking if it exists.

Comment: I'm sorry.  It does not

Comment: I see, try adding a `const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchCodes, fetchLang };` and `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CodeDisplay)`.

Comment: Its working!! thanks bud.  how do i accept this as an answer?  i'm a noob at this as well

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are missing a `mapDispatchToProps` object to pass to the `connect` HOC. This means the `fetchCodes` and `fetchLang` action creators aren't wrapped in a call to `dispatch` nor are they injected as props to be accessed in the component.

Add a `mapDispatchToProps` and pass along to `connect` after `mapStateToProps`.

```
...
const mapDispatchToProps = { fetchCodes, fetchLang };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CodeDisplay);
```